# Check if JSON array contains string passed by variable value

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell

How can I check if a certain string is in a JSON array?

JSON array:

```json
["domain","password","root","url","user"]
```

I need to check if "domain", "password", "root", "url", "user" are inside the array or not.

```
ad=("domain" "password" "root" "url" "user")
keys=$(kubectl get secret ssss --context rrrr -n test -o jsonpath=\{$.data\} | jq -c 'keys')

 for value in "${keys[@]}"; do
   key+=($value)
 done
 #echo ${key[@]}

 for string in ${ad[@]}; do
  if [ "$key"== "$string" ]; then 
   echo ${string[@]}
   echo ${key[@]}
  fi
done
```

Comment: Do you need to check if they are **all** in the `ad` array, or **any**?

Comment: @glennjackman - any

Comment: What's the purpose of the first `for` loop? It seems like it's just appending the `keys` array to itself.

Comment: You need spaces around `==` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar - yes you right

Comment: You've already got jq in the pipeline, so you can check there: `kubectl_cmd | jq -e --args 'keys | any(IN($ARGS.positional[]))' "${ad[@]}" > /dev/null && echo "keys contains at least one of ad" || echo "no key is in ad"`